# Mutliple Session Pages in ASP.NET Application Being Injected into Single ASP.Net Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session

We are testing multiple sessions in an ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms application that has recently exhibited some troubling behavior.

Recently a postback was performed on one of our pages say for User Session One and when the postback occurred two pages from two different sessions were injected into a single ASP.Net Master Page.

The HTTP session header information was also in the page footer from the first page.

[image]

We checked our session database tables and can see the two users session information and verified that they were testing this application at about the same time, however we are trying to determine what might cause this issue.

We are currently pursuing multiple approaches to determine a root cause to this issue, however we thought the Stack Overflow community may have some input in the meantime.

Thanks

Comment: I think, at least you should provide some code you think is causing this issue. Or any configuration.

Comment: Did you declare user variables as `static` somewhere?

Comment: The code base is rather large, however a search in VS reveals that there are declared static user variables in use.

Comment: Just remember that a static variable is the same for all users, so do not store user specific data in there.